# Two-Way Lookup w/ Index and Match

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range, match

Trying to match row `A1:L1` and columns `B2:B16,C2:C16,F2:F16,G2:G16,J2:J16,K2:K16` and return their Qtys. The inputs/outputs are in the red/green boxes. The second match in the formula is working when I step through it. The first match in the formula produces a #N/A and is the issue.

| 10/21/22 Apple | Color Code Apple | Color Code Berry | 10/21/22 Berry | 11/4/22 Apple | Color Code Apple | Color Code Berry | 11/4/22 Berry | 12/21/22 Apple | Color Code Apple | Color Code Berry | 12/21/22 Berry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 221021apple1 | 221021berry1 | 45 | 5 | 221104apple10 | 221104berry7 | 4,545 | 65 | 221221apple2 | 221221berry4 | 22 |
| 2 | 221021apple2 | 221021berry20 | 5 | 9 | 221104apple32 | 221104berry8 | 1,313 | 11 | 221221apple12 | 221221berry13 | 2 |
| 3 | 221021apple3 | 221021berry39 | 8 | 4 | 221104apple54 | 221104berry9 | 1,212 | 5,656 | 221221apple22 | 221221berry22 | 2 |
| 5 | 221021apple4 | 221021berry58 | 56 | 45 | 221104apple76 | 221104berry10 | 22 | 42 | 221221apple32 | 221221berry31 | 0 |
| 8 | 221021apple5 | 221021berry77 | 3 | 65 | 221104apple98 | 221104berry11 | 22 | 54,242 | 221221apple42 | 221221berry40 | 333 |
| 6,666 | 221021apple6 | 221021berry96 | 88 | 98 | 221104apple120 | 221104berry12 | 222 | 4 | 221221apple52 | 221221berry49 | 222 |
| 2 | 221021apple7 | 221021berry115 | 66 | 78 | 221104apple142 | 221104berry13 | 2 | 424 | 221221apple62 | 221221berry58 | 244 |
| 3 | 221021apple8 | 221021berry134 | 44 | 32 | 221104apple164 | 221104berry14 | 22 | 2,323 | 221221apple72 | 221221berry67 | 44 |
| 4,744 | 221021apple9 | 221021berry153 | 22 | 56 | 221104apple186 | 221104berry15 | 2 | 424 | 221221apple82 | 221221berry76 | 123 |
| 55,151 | 221021apple10 | 221021berry172 | 88 | 12 | 221104apple208 | 221104berry16 | 2 | 5 | 221221apple92 | 221221berry85 | 111 |
| 2,121 | 221021apple11 | 221021berry191 | 12 | 5,555 | 221104apple230 | 221104berry17 | 2 | 4,242 | 221221apple102 | 221221berry94 | 456 |
|  | 221021apple12 | 221021berry210 | 36 | 2,222 | 221104apple252 | 221104berry18 | 5 | 1,212 | 221221apple112 | 221221berry103 | 789 |
| 48,484 | 221021apple13 | 221021berry229 | 58 | 888 | 221104apple274 | 221104berry19 | 2 | 444 | 221221apple122 | 221221berry112 | 888 |
| 6,541 | 221021apple14 | 221021berry248 | 5 | 7 | 221104apple296 | 221104berry20 | 4 | 2,222 | 221221apple132 | 221221berry121 | 55 |
| 77 | 221021apple15 | 221021berry267 | 96 | 43 | 221104apple318 | 221104berry21 | 4 | 42 | 221221apple142 | 221221berry130 | 222 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| A1:L1 | Col. B,C,F,G,J,K | Qty |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 10/21/22 Apple | 221021apple10 | 55,151 | Returns A11 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 12/21/22 Berry | 221221berry49 | 222 | Returns L7 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Formula in cell `C19`:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A2:L16, MATCH(Sheet1!B19,Sheet1!A2:L16,0), MATCH(Sheet1!A19,Sheet1!A1:L1,0))
```

Formula in cell `C20`:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A2:L16, MATCH(Sheet1!B20,Sheet1!A2:L16,0), MATCH(Sheet1!A20,Sheet1!A1:L1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: I really don't understand how you're getting the output from the inputs. Can you give detailed steps as to how it works?

Comment: What does "looking for the correct date and fruit type" mean? And "return the amounts based on these inputs"? You're using vague terms. Can you be very prescriptive?

Comment: Please make your data useful by  **editing your question** to post it as **text**, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I tried to explain it more by updating my description and being more detailed along w/ redoing the picture to explain more. I hope this gets across my intention for the Index/Match formula I am trying to derive.

Comment: @mjac Post those as text table so that we can copy.

Comment: Ok I think I generated the table right so you can copy. I didn't know how to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C19 formula

```
=OFFSET($A$1,MATCH(B19,OFFSET($A$2:$A$16,,IF(MOD(MATCH(Sheet1!A19,Sheet1!$A$1:$L$1,0),2)=0,MATCH(Sheet1!A19,Sheet1!$A$1:$L$1,0)-1,MATCH(Sheet1!A19,Sheet1!$A$1:$L$1,0)+1)-1),0),MATCH(Sheet1!A19,Sheet1!$A$1:$L$1,0)-1)
```

C20 formula

```
=OFFSET($A$1,MATCH(B20,OFFSET($A$2:$A$16,,IF(MOD(MATCH(Sheet1!A20,Sheet1!$A$1:$L$1,0),2)=0,MATCH(Sheet1!A20,Sheet1!$A$1:$L$1,0)-1,MATCH(Sheet1!A20,Sheet1!$A$1:$L$1,0)+1)-1),0),MATCH(Sheet1!A20,Sheet1!$A$1:$L$1,0)-1)
```

If you are using M365, `let` formula is simpiler.

C19 formula

```
=LET(c,MATCH(Sheet1!A19,Sheet1!$A$1:$L$1,0),
    col,OFFSET($A$2:$A$16,,IF(MOD(c,2)=0,c-2,c)),
    r,MATCH(Sheet1!B19,col,0),
    OFFSET($A$1,r,c-1))
```

Comment: If you are using M365, `let` formula is simpiler.

Comment: I wish I was. Still using 2019 version. Thanks.

Comment: An upvote to my question would help get some points back also. I would appreciate it. Thanks.